# Wordpress site suddenly stops showing up

Tags: wordpress

[image]

I am new to Wordpress. I have this wordpress site which was running quite fine till  1 or 2 days before but now it doesnt show up anything. I am not able to trace what the problem is. Please help

Comment: Which theme are u using??

Comment: Wordpress Professional

Comment: Did you do anything new like IP blocking?

Comment: Did you change any of your theme's code? It is very likely that this is a "WordPress White Screen of Death". Use the term in Google and you will find plenty of steps that might help you solve the problem.

Comment: Does this only happen, if you are logged in? Try accessing the page in private browsing mode or delete all site-related cookies to check, whether the white screen appears only when you are logged in.

Comment: I didnt change anything

Comment: This is an unusual case because there aren't any JS console errors, the URL is literally coming back as a cancel. WSOD wouldn't do that.

Comment: @john have you tried putting in a simple html file in root and accessing that directly? Could be an IP routing issue. We had that happen with a site recently and had to go to the hosting company to fix.

Comment: I tried running in private browsing but no result

Comment: Yeah I tried it is working now. but after some time site automatically goes down. It is happening since last 3-4 hrs when I got to know about this

Comment: Then it's not a WP issue. It's a server/hosting issue.

Comment: But it was working fine yesterday

Comment: And if it was a hosting problem then site would not have been loaded even once. You can see the loaded site screenshot below

Comment: Activate `WP_DEBUG` by changing the line `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` to `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in _wp-config.php_ in order to see if there is any PHP error showing up.

Answer (score 0):

Site is working. may be you are using any proxy or hotspot

[image: site working]

Comment: It sometimes goes up and sometimes stays down